# MAUI How to emulate screen width of android being 1080?

Tags: android, maui

I do posess a physical Honor 8, which has got a resolution of 1920x1080. I am trying to create an emulator with the same screen size. I did this with the Android Device Manager. I have set the hw.Display.Width there to 1080 and the Height to 1920. When I run my app in the emulator, it shows   DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height == 1920, but DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width == 1200.
How come? How can I emulate Width = 1080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on how to emulate some arbitrary screen width in an Android emulator:

It's easy: Just put a Border around everything and set its WidthRequest to my desire.